# Convergence of stochastic processes and integral

Tags: integration, convergence-divergence, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

Let $X_n(t)$ and $X(t)$ are bounded stochastic processes ($|X_n(t)|<C$ and $|X(t)<C|$) such that for each $t\in[0,T]$ 
$$
X_n(t) \to X(t) \text{ as }  n\to\infty \text{ almost surely }.  
$$

The question is following: Can we conclude 
$$
\int_0^T(X_n(t) - X(t))^2\, dt \to 0 \text{ as } n\to \infty \text{ almost surely }?
$$

Comment: Yes, it follows from bounded convergence theorem.

Comment: @Solitary I thought the bounded convergence theorem say that $(X_n(t) - X(t))^2\to 0$. But here integration by time $t$.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "$X_n(t)$ and $X(t)$ are bounded stochastic processes"? Does there exist a constant $C>0$ such that $|X_n(t)| \leq C$ for all $n$ and $t$ or does the bound $C$ depend on $n$ (or $t$)?

Comment: @saz $C$ does not depend on $n$ or $t$.

Comment: I see; thanks..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The claim is indeed a straight-forward application of the dominated convergence theorem. For fixed $\omega$ set $$f_n(t) := (X_n(t,\omega)-X(t,\omega))^2,$$ then by assumption $f_n(t) \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$ for each $t$ and moreover, $|f_n(t)| \leq C$ for some constant $C$ (not depending on $n$ or $t$). Applying the dominated convergence theorem proves the claim.

Note that it is important that the bound $C$ does not depend on $n$ or $t$; otherwise the claim does, in general, not hold.